# #xampp# I want to access "localhost/htaccess/test/" then it would skip to "localhost/htaccess/index.php", but it not work in windows

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

This is my test file [htaccess.zip](http://www.zzbec.pw/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/htaccess.zip)

Here is process of test:

step one: install xampp

step two: move htaccess file that extracted from htaccess.zip to ***D:\xampp\htdocs***

step three: type ***localhost/htaccess/test/*** into firefox address bar

step four: waiting the result of showing ***localhost/htaccess/index.php*** instead of showing ***localhost/htaccess/test/index.php***

it works on linux. how to fix it so that it can work in windows as well?

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /htaccess/

RewriteRule ^test/?$ index\.php
```

Comment: Explain your question and problem clearly.

Comment: The code which you have provided in zip file is small enough to be included in your question here. It would save others' efforts.